# praw, Invalid leading whitespace, reserved character(s), or returncharacter(s) in header value

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, reddit, praw

```
try:
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, user_agent=USER_AGENT, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    hot_posts = reddit.subreddit('seriea').hot(limit=30)
    for submission in hot_posts: # this is the line that creates the error
        print(submission)
except Exception as e:
    trace_back = sys.exc_info()[2]
    line = trace_back.tb_lineno
    print("Process Exception in line {}".format(line), e)
```

I get this:

```
Process Exception in line 373 error with request Invalid leading whitespace, reserved character(s), or returncharacter(s) in header value: ' PRAW/7.6.0 prawcore/2.3.0'
```

I never had a problem like this in praw.... I don't understand what is going on.. Is there something that reddit changed and so praw doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET and credentials, and now it works.